# Inherit Excel Range Interface

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net

I would like to use the built in Excel Range interface and add some custom properties.
For example the Range interface does not have a .LastColumn property.

I tried:

```
Public Sub TestIt()
        Xl = CType(GetObject(, "Excel.Application"), Application)
        Wb = Xl.ActiveWorkbook
        Sht = Wb.ActiveSheet

        Dim rng1 As New MyRange1
        rng1.Rng = Xl.Range("Test")

        Dim rng2 As MyRange2 'New cannot be used on an interface.
        rng2 = Xl.Range("Test")
    End Sub

Public Class MyRange1
    Property Rng As Range
    Property LastColumn As Integer
End Class

Public Interface MyRange2
    Inherits Range
    Property LastColumn As Integer
End Interface
```

To access items of the Excel Range I have to type e.g.

```
rng1.Rng.Column
rng1.LastColumn
```

But I would like to have it this way:

```
rng2.Column
rng2.LastColumn
```

On this line:

```
rng2 = Xl.Range("Test")
```

I get this error:

An exception error of type System.InvalidCastException occurred in TestApp.exe.
Additional information: The COM object of type "System.__ComObject" cannot be converted to the interface type "TestApp.MyRange2". This operation could not be performed because the QueryInterface call to the COM component for the interface with IID "{42E1E51A-29B8-317C-9B69-30VC823A943B}" could not be performed due to the following error: Interface not supported (HRESULT exception: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

I think this is to be expected, as I don’t really know how inheritance works in this case.

Can anyone help me to implement that?

Comment: You might find it worth while to expand on _it doesn’t work_. A clear explanation of exactly how it doesn’t work for example.  Also see you don’t appear to be creating a new instance of either MyRange1 or MyRange2 so kind of wondering if there might be some code missing from your examples

Comment: You are right, I now have edited my initial post.